# Set decimal on last two points

Tags: python

I dont find out how i can set the decimal (point) to the two last numbers...

I tried this `'{0:.2f}'.format(a)` but that makes like this `'117085.00'`

This is what i have

```
117085
55688
```

And i want

```
1170.85
 556.88
```

So i need a point at the last two numbers.
And i dont want new numbers, i only need to set the point

Can someone help at this (easy i think) problem? :/ i am really new

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make float values in Python display .00 instead of .0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368514/how-to-make-float-values-in-python-display-00-instead-of-0)

Comment: @JohanC That's bad. The `0.01` is already inaccurate, and then you use that inaccurate number in a calculation. Better do `/100`.

Comment: `x = 117085` and `x/100`

Comment: @JohanC For example, `35 * 0.01` is `0.35000000000000003` while `35 / 100` is `0.35`.

Comment: @JohanC Not sure about that rounding, all I remember is that the standard guarantees the division result to be the closest representable number. But you don't get that when you you're going into a multiplication with an already inaccurate value. And the `*0.01` way is *consistently* the bad one: https://repl.it/repls/WrongAdolescentParallelport

Comment: @JohanC Has nothing to do with "trailing 999's", either. Neither of the two values has any. Your result is precisely 0.350000000000000033306690738754696212708950042724609375 while mine is precisely 0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375, and the latter is closer to the "ideal" result 0.35 (as mentioned, it's as close as possible to that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this, the question isn't a matter of formatting but dividing numbers. I can't see this being useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [33]: x = 117085                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

In [34]: x/100                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[34]: 1170.85
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are receiving your numbers, they are 100x the value you are trying to print. To format them the way you want, divide them by 100 before formatting them.

Additionally, the example you provide appears to be right-justified, meaning that the right side all lines up. If you want to accomplish that, you can use something like the below:

```py
a = 117085
b = 55688

print('{0:>7.2f}'.format(a / 100))
print('{0:>7.2f}'.format(b / 100))
```

Output:

```
1170.85
 556.88
```

**Edit:** Converted the `rjust(7)` to the format string `>7`

Let's break down the format string that we're using above...

```
{0:>7.2f} # The whole string
{       } # Brackets to denote a processed value
 0        # Take the first argument passed through the `format()` function
  :       # A delimiter to separate the identifier (in this case, 0) from the format notation
   >7     # Right justify this element, with a width of 7
     .2f  # Format the input as a float, with 2 digits to the right of the decimal point
```

Python implicitly assumes a few things apparently, so here's a shorter alternative:

```
{:7.2f} # The whole string
{     } # Brackets to denote a processed value
 :      # A delimiter to separate the identifier (in this case, assumed 0) from the format notation
  7     # justify this element (Right justification by default), with a width of 7
   .2f  # Format the input as a float, with 2 digits to the right of the decimal point
```

Comment: Format strings aren't always the clearest things to read, but there ya go.